# Populating XAML ListView ItemsSource programmatically

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, data-binding, cross-platform

I am trying to create a Xamarin cross-platform app.
I chose a template and now I have a MainPage, and ItemsPage.
I think ItemsPage is called by MainPage.

I have this code in ItemsPage.xaml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="App1.Views.ItemsPage"
             Title="{Binding Title}"
             x:Name="BrowseItemsPage">

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Add" Clicked="AddItem_Clicked" />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

    <StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="ItemsListView"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                HasUnevenRows="true"
                RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}"
                IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
                IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}"
                CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
                ItemSelected="OnItemSelected">

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Padding="10">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Text}" 
                                d:Text="{Binding .}"
                                LineBreakMode="NoWrap" 
                                Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" 
                                FontSize="16" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Description}" 
                                d:Text="Item descripton"
                                LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                                Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}"
                                FontSize="13" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>

    </ContentPage>
```

and this code in ItemsPage.cs

```
    public ItemsPage()
    {
            InitializeComponent();

            BindingContext = viewModel = new ItemsViewModel();
            string[] files = folderEntryListinAssets("folderName");

            ObservableCollection<String> entries = new ObservableCollection<String>();

            for (var i=0;i<files.Length;i++)
            {
               Console.WriteLine("app output - entry "+files[i]);
               entries.Add(files[i]);
            }
            ItemsListView.ItemsSource = entries;           
        }


    private String[] folderEntryListinAssets(String folderName)
    {                           
                switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
                {
                    case Device.Android:
                    Context context = Android.App.Application.Context;

                    String[] list=context.Assets.List(folderName);
                    Console.WriteLine("app output - list size " + list.Length);
                    for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
                    { Console.WriteLine("app output - entry "+list.GetValue(i).ToString()); }


                    return list;
                   /* case Device.UWP:
                        path = "ms-appx-web:///";
                        return path;
                case Device.iOS:
                    path = NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath;
                    return path;*/
                    default:

                    return null;
                }
```

I see nothing.

Note that I removed the default strings in XAML, they were correctly displayed.

Now I need to programmatically set the ItemsSource, as shown above.

I see that the entries are created as strings in the console log.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: In XAML you set listview's ItemsSource to be a binding (`ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"`), i.e ItemSource will be set in viewmodel, but why are you setting ItemSource in code-behind too?

Comment: @Vahid I tried your suggestion but it does not display anything If I put 'ItemsSource="{Binding entries}"' in XAML and comment 'ItemsListView.ItemsSource = entries;' in code, provided I am now using the answer I accepted

Comment: You need to decide how are you gonna set ItemSource, if in code-behind then the way I did it in my answer is correct, but if in viewmodel, then you need to comment setting ItemSource in code-behind and set it in viewmodel i.e in ItemsViewModel, which must be set correctly as a viewmodel.

Comment: @Vahid Yes I am gradually remembering how all this work, so I restored 'ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"', then set 'ObservableCollection<Models.Item> entries = new ObservableCollection<Models.Item>();' but if I put viewModel.Items = entries; it does not display anything.

Comment: Then I guess would be the viewmodel is not set correctly. maybe Items property doesn't call _OnPropertyChanged_. But this would be a new problem that can be asked as a new question on stackoverflow.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is the way you set *ItemSource* and bindings in viewcell.
According to your viewcell, it expects each item to be a model in which there are two properties: *Text* and *Description*, i.e the ItemSourse must be collection of that model.

You should have a model like this:

```
public class MyModel{
    public string Text{get;set;}
    public string Description{get;set;}
}
```

And you need to set ItemSource like this:

```
ObservableCollection<MyModel> entries = new ObservableCollection<MyModel>();

for (var i = 0; i<files.Length; i++)
{
Console.WriteLine("app output - entry " + files[i]);

var model = new MyModel
{
    Text = "text value",
    Description = "description value"
};

entries.Add(model);
}
ItemsListView.ItemsSource = entries;
```

Finally it depends on you how to fill each model i.e Text and Description.